# Get memory usage of COO sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy

How can I infer the memory usage of a sparse COO format matrix

**Data**

```
row  = np.array([0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0])
col  = np.array([0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0])
data = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
mat = coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(4, 4))
```

Online I found solutions that don't seem to work with coo martrices:

```
mat.data.nbytes + mat.indptr.nbytes + mat.indices.nbytes
```

only `mat.data.nbytes` does not return an error, but the size is much smaller than it should be (when creating a large sparse matrix from dataframe columns). Am I missing any components here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html) more carefully -> see *Attributes*

It's

```
mat.data.nbytes + mat.row.nbytes + mat.col.nbytes
```

You copy-pasted something tuned for csr/csc matrices (see their *Attributes*).